# Toggle different math fonts with XeLaTeX

Tags: math-mode, xetex, fontspec, unicode-math, sans-serif

My goal is to use a sans serif math font in all figures and I found several approaches with my favourite being the use of `\mathversion` and the `unicode-math` package to change between  different math fonts.
However, I am not able to switch between fonts due to the warning

> Package fontspec Warning: Font "Latin Modern Math" does not contain requested
> (fontspec)                Script "Math".

that repeats for all fonts I import with a `[version=]` parameter. However, I can change the math font for the whole document.

So my question: What am I doing wrong? I basically copied my code from another answer (will add the link when I find it again).

My mwe for testing is

```
\documentclass[authoryear,preprint,5p,11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[]{unicode-math}
\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase, Ligatures=TeX }
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[version=lm]
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[version=pagella]

\begin{document}
This is some text.

And a figure with maths elements
\begin{figure}[ht]
  % \mathversion{sansmath}
 \begin{pgfpicture}
 \pgftext[x=0.691229in,y=0.540666in,,top]{\sffamily\selectfont 125}%
 \pgftext[x=0.354158in,y=0.432447in,left,base]{\sffamily\selectfont \(\displaystyle \frac{-\pi}{2}\)}%
 \pgftext[x=1.054158in,y=0.432447in,left,base]{\sffamily\selectfont \(\displaystyle 10^{3123x} \cdot 12389\)}%
 \end{pgfpicture}
\end{figure}
and a formula
\[ \frac{\pi}{2.42132}= \beta\]
 and some math in another font
\mathversion{lm}
\[ \frac{\pi}{2.42132}= \beta\]
 and yet another one
\mathversion{pagella}
 \[\frac{123456} {some text}\]

\end{document}
```

The full logfile is here: https://pastebin.com/kS3quC7A

Comment: I don't get your warnings. Is your system up-to-date? Can you show the complete log-file?

Comment: Added the logfile. System should be very much up to date, I just reinstalled texlive.

Comment: well your system is not really up-to-date, you have eg a latex format from februar, and mine is from october. But imho the main problem is that your xelatex seems to find some mathjax fonts: `LatinModernMathJax_Size1-Regular/OT`  and similar for Pagella: `GyrePagellaMathJax_Symbols-Regular/OT` and this fonts confuses it. Try if it works if you use filenames like `latinmodern-math.otf` instead of the font name.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This is indeed the origin of the problem. I did not draw the connection to a font mixing issue. If I use the font names from the files installed in `/usr/local/share/fonts/OTF` it's working well. You may raise your comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your log shows that xelatex is finding mathjax fonts:

`LatinModernMathJax_Size1-Regular/OT` and similar for Pagella: `GyrePagellaMathJax_Symbols-Regular/OT` and these fonts confuses it.

Try if it works if you use filenames like `latinmodern-math.otf` instead of the font names.

Answer (score 2):

The only OpenType sans serif math font I know of is GFS Neohellenic Math.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[]{unicode-math}

\setsansfont{GFSNeohellenic}[
  Extension=.otf,
  UprightFont=*,
  ItalicFont=*It,
  BoldFont=*Bold,
  BoldItalicFont=*BoldIt,
]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{GFSNeohellenicMath.otf}[version=sansmath]

\begin{document}
This is some text.

And a figure with maths elements

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\sffamily\mathversion{sansmath}

\[
125+\frac{-\pi}{2}+10^{3123x} \cdot 12389+\sin3
\]

\caption{Whatever}

\end{figure}

and a formula
\[ \frac{\pi}{2.42132}= \beta\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very very nice the font GFSNeohellenicMath.otf. I put this question between my favorities.

Comment: There's also Fira Math.

Comment: Yes, that's true, I could perhaps do something similar. I still don't know why I can not use the `mathversion` command to switch fonts. I can successfully change all math in the document to some sans serif like Fira Math or Nimbus Sans Math but not in combination with other fonts.I'll see what I can take from your example.